# why is alert defined twice in safari?

Tags: javascript, safari

why is alert defined twice in safari?

Safari 5.1.7(7534.57.2)

```
window.hasOwnProperty('alert'); //true

var w = Object.getPrototypeOf(window);

w.hasOwnProperty('alert'); //true
```

Other browsers:Chrome 24.0.1312.52 m,FireFox 18.0,IE 9.0.8112.16421CO,Opera 12.12 1707

```
window.hasOwnProperty('alert'); //false

var w = Object.getPrototypeOf(window);

w.hasOwnProperty('alert'); //true
```

Comment: Note that, in Safari, `window.alert('foo')` works as expected but `Object.getPrototypeOf(window).alert('foo')` throws a `TypeError`.

Comment: good point Matt, but what is the use of Window.prototype.alert in safari?

Comment: Note that `window` is a host object and does not have to play by the rules (other than what's defined in the spec).

Answer (score 0):

This implies that in Safari, they setup alert as a function on the prototype and the window instance.

```
function Window() {
    this.alert = function() { //code here };
}

Window.prototype.alert = function() { //code here };
```

Whereas in the other browsers they would have only done the prototype declaration.